# How to show my base 64 string into iframe?

Tags: javascript, base64

I have base 64 string.

```
var data =" JVBERi0xLjQNJeLjz9MNCjc1MDEgMCBvYmogPDwvTGluZWFyaXplZCAxL0wgOTM2NDM1Mi9PIDc1MDMvRSAxMjE3ODgvTiA1MjIvVCA5MjE0MjgzL0ggWyA2..";
```

I have also iframe

How can I convert my base 64 string and convert it into pdf and show it into my iframe

```
<iframe src={myConvertedPdfToShow}>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your base64 string is incorrect it should be

```js
let data = "data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjQNJeLjz9MNCjc1MDEgMCBvYmogPDwvTGluZWFyaXplZCAxL0wgOTM2NDM1Mi9PIDc1MDMvRSAxMjE3ODgvTiA1MjIvVCA5MjE0MjgzL0ggWyA2...";
```

if that doesnt work consider this example below.

```html
<object data="your_url_to_pdf" type="application/pdf">
    <iframe src="https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=your_url_to_pdf&embedded=true"></iframe>
</object>
```